# How to group by date and make columns from values?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

I have a table for orders with two columns: `shipping_id` that references a shipping method and `packed` that keeps the date when the order has been packed.

```
+-------------+------------+
| shipping_id |   packed   |
+-------------+------------+
| 1           | 2017-05-07 |
| 1           | 2017-05-06 |
| 2           | 2017-05-06 |
| 2           | 2017-05-06 |
| 3           | 2017-05-05 |
+-------------+------------+
```

I need to somehow group the results by the date `packed`, shipping types put as the columns and values of the cells be the counts of orders that has been packed that day and with that shipping method. Something like this:

```
+------------+---+---+---+
|    date    | 1 | 2 | 3 |
+------------+---+---+---+
| 2017-05-05 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2017-05-06 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2017-05-07 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+------------+---+---+---+
```

Is this possible in MySQL? How would the SQL query look like?

Thank you

Comment: There can be an infinite number of distinct shipping_ids every day?

Comment: I suspect you need mysql conditional aggregation with dynamic sql.

Comment: @P.Salmon Shippings are stored in separate table to which the ids reference. And yes, theoretically their number isn't limited.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký answer update with the full PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll not be able to do it with vanilla SQL query, you'll have to use Stored Procedure.

For Dynamic pivot, take a look at [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns) , but you'll see it's not really easy to use: the `GROUP_CONCAT()` is limited to 1024 bytes by default and you'll need the right to make and use procedure.

---

The Vanilla SQL give you **Query 1** at best.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdc3fe/12)

**Query 1**:

```
select `shipping_id`, `packed`, count(1) as nb
from t
group by `shipping_id`, `packed`
order by `packed`, `shipping_id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdc3fe/12/0)**:

```
| shipping_id |     packed | nb |
|-------------|------------|----|
|           3 | 2017-05-05 |  1 |
|           1 | 2017-05-06 |  1 |
|           2 | 2017-05-06 |  2 |
|           1 | 2017-05-07 |  1 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SET @sql = NULL
```

**Query 3**:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'COUNT(IF(shipping_id = ''',
      shipping_id,
      ''', 1, NULL)) AS `',
      shipping_id,'`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM t
```

**Query 4**:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT packed, ', @sql, ' FROM t GROUP BY packed ORDER BY `packed`')
```

**Query 5**:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql
```

**Query 6**:

```
EXECUTE stmt
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cdc3fe/12/5)**:

```
|     packed | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|------------|---|---|---|
| 2017-05-05 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2017-05-06 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2017-05-07 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
```

**Query 7**:

```
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt
```

Comment: Dont use `*` in the select when using aggregation. This query may work now but may stop working if new columns are added in the future. State the column names explicitly.

Comment: @GurV updated ;)

Comment: @GurV BTW, congratulation for your gold `SQL` !